# I have a problem with my react-native project

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

afterly i have a problem to us reslove
then this is error
in todolist(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
ERROR  Error: Text strings must be rendered within a  component.

This error is located at:
in text (created by HomeScreen)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by ScrollView)
in RCTScrollView (created by ScrollView)
in ScrollView (created by ScrollView)
in ScrollView (created by Container)
in Container (created by HomeScreen)
in HomeScreen (created by App)
in App
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in todolist(RootComponent), js engine: hermes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DFgQ.png)

i to try to change children but i has been the problem
help me , please , i'm learn creating app with react-native

Comment: The error is clear — you have text outside a component. But, since you haven’t shown any code, it’s not possible to show a solution. Please see [ask]

Comment: Very bad post title. Read the how to ask page! Welcome to Stackoverflow.